# Showing that a function is affine in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I'm reading an analysis book, and I'm struggling with a question. First, here is the definition for an affine function:

> A function is said to be ***affine*** if it is defined by
>
> $$g(u) = c + \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}u_{i}$$
>
> where $c$ and the $a_{i}'s$ are prescribed values. If $c = 0,$ the
>   function is linear.

Now, here's the problem:

> Fix a point $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and let $c$ be a point in
>   $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and define $\phi : \mathbb{R}^{n} : \mathbb{R}$ by 
>   $$\phi(u) = \langle c, u - x \rangle .$$
>
> (a) Show that $\phi : \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is
>   affine.
>
> (b) Show that given any nonconstant affine function $\phi :
>  \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, it is possible to choose
>   points $x, c \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ so that $\phi : \mathbb{R}^{n}
>  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has the above form.

For (a), I used the bilinearity property of the inner product as follows:

$$\langle c, u - x \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_{i}u_{i}  - \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_{i}x_{i}.$$

I don't know how to get it into the form used in the definition, though. I also don't know how to get an arbitrary affine function into the form provided above. I'm guessing you start with $c + \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}u_{i}$ and manipulate it into what we want. I tried a lot of things, but I couldn't get it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use of $c$ for a number in a) and for a vector in b) is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For b) take $x_0=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ and $x =-\frac c {\|(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)\|^{2}} x_0$. Then $\langle x_0, (u-x) \rangle =c+\sum a_i u_i$.

Comment: If a) holds with $a_i=0$ for all $i$ and $c \neq 0$ then it is not possible to prove b).

Comment: how come there is an extra point $x_{0}$? shouldn't we be choosing $x$ and $c$ only? or is $x_{0}$ supposed to be $c$?

Comment: Well, as I have commented above you are using $c$ for a number in a) and a vector in b). They are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The term $-\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_ix_i$ is just a constant since $<c,u-x>$ is only a function of $u$.  So, it does have the form of the affine function in the definition.

Part (b) follows from the fact that any number in $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as a linear combination of other numbers in $\mathbb{R}$ ($\mathbb{R}$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication).